# Recaptcha V2 layout is broken after page loading

Tags: jquery, forms, recaptcha

After executing the code below, the layout of the reCAPTCHA v2 section in the form is broken. However, it functions properly after manually refreshing the page.

```
location.reload();
```

This is in Safari